# Mysql Query for counting rows with specific days difference

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Going to make a line graph. I want to query count with difference of 5 days.
Suppose if I have following rows:

```
 booking_date
 2015-02-1
 2015-02-3
 2015-02-5
 2015-02-6
 2015-02-6
 2015-02-9
 2015-02-10
 2015-02-15
 2015-02-17
 2015-02-23
 2015-02-28
```

In above table column it contains date. Now How can I do mysql query so that it can return with difference of 5 days like:

```
 1 => 3  // count of date between 2015-02-1 & 2015-02-05 is 3
 2 => 4  // count of date between 2015-02-06 & 2015-02-10 is 4
 3 => 1  // count of date between 2015-02-11 & 2015-02-15 is 1
 4 => 1  // count of date between 2015-02-16 & 2015-02-20 is 1
 5 => 1  // count of date between 2015-02-21 & 2015-02-25 is 1
 6 => 1  // count of date between 2015-02-26 & 2015-02-30 is 1
```

Is any direct way to query like above. I am not so good at mysql. But can do php nicely.

Comment: you can use a solution that's almost identical to the way you've asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to get everything in the same query.

First of all get the unix timestamp for the date you want to start grouping in 5 days. In your example that would be 2015-02-01 -> 1422748800

Then the query would be the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(booking_date) - 1422748800)/ (60*60*24*5)) as FiveDayPackNumber from tbl GROUP BY FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(booking_date) - 1422748800)/ (60*60*24*5))
```

Haven't tested it so it may require some tweaking but you can get the idea: It will group them by the number of 5-days-packs that passed since your initial date, starting at 0.

Comment: Hi, i tired this but got unexpected result. There are 3 counts from 2015-2-0 to 2015-2-5 but it shows 4 count. Why is this happening.

Comment: Provide your example and data in a sqlfiddle and let's find out

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM {table_name} WHERE booking_date > 2015-02-01 AND booking_date < 2015-02-05
```

?

(completely off memory so you might need to slightly alter it)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE booking_date >= start_date
    AND booking_date <= end_date
```